# Go-lang Error using regex

Tags: regex, go

I have a little problem with a regex using the "regexp" package in go.

This regex should return to me the substring inside the brackets "[]"

`\[(.*?)\]` used on `@class my-div [button] {` should return `[ button, hello ]`

So, in Go I tried something like:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile('\[(.*?)\]')

fmt.Println(re.MatchString(header)) // false

return re.FindString(header) // header = "@class my-div [button] {"
```

And also:

```
re := regexp.QuoteMeta("\\\[\(\.\*\?\)\\\]") // <= Changed

fmt.Println(re.MatchString(header)) // false

return re.FindString(header) // header = "@class my-div [button] {"
```

And many other variants, but still doesn't work...

I also tried to use an online regex tester for go, and it works perfectly, so I really don't understand why it doesn't work in go....
http://fiddle.re/57y4c6

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/Z_-1EEKgaW

Help me please and Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier if you just use a raw string literal for regexes, rather than trying to double escape reserved characters. This will compile correctly, and work the same as the fiddle.re example you posted:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\[(.*?)\]`)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Resolved ! The problem was that I continued to use the ' char thinking that was equal to the ` one. (Italian keyboard...)