# PHP regex pattern for password checking not working in Go

Tags: regex, go, pattern-matching

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518130/go-lang-error-using-regex), I know I need to use a backquotes ( ` ) to wrap my regex pattern. Now I have regex pattern `/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$/` to check password pattern whether is correct. I have tested it with PHP and it work correctly. But it does not work in Go. Why?

By the way, what is the type of backquoted ( ` ) variable? it seems not `string` type. How can I declare this variable container?

**Testing Code**

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main(){
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$/`)
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString("aSfd46Fgwaq"))
}
```

**Testing Result**

```
Running...

panic: regexp: Compile(`/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$/`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4efae0, 0xc82000a340)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
regexp.MustCompile(0x576140, 0x4b, 0x100000000)
    /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:232 +0x16f
main.main()
    /home/casper/.local/share/data/liteide/goplay.go:9 +0x30
exit status 2

Error: process exited with code 1.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Go regex does not support lookarounds and regex delimiters.

Comment: Is there any other plugins that I can `go get` from github to use for this regex pattern?

Comment: The `(?!.*\s)` lookahead is redundant since the consuming pattern does not match whitespaces.

Comment: Check https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - Is there any other good regex pattern choice for checking password in go regexp?

Comment: The backtick ( ` ) is used for raw strings. They have the exact same type as normal strings (created with ") but they don't handle backslashes (writing `\n` will result in a string that contains the characters \ and n, not in a line break).

Comment: It is difficult to find regex pattern without `(?=` for checking password.

Comment: @CasperLI: You can really do it without lookaheads. Just split the conditions, here is pseudo code: `if str.length >= 8 && s =~ /\d/ && && s =~ /[a-z]/ && s =~ /[A-Z]/ && s =~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go regexp does not support lookarounds. Also, the `/.../` regex delimiters are not supported, either (there are special methods in Go to express those).

You may either use a lookaround-supporting regex library for Go ([here is a PCRE-supporting one](https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre)) or split the conditions and use several small, readable regexps:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    s := "aSfd46Fgwaq"
    lower_cond := regexp.MustCompile(`[a-z]`)
    upper_cond := regexp.MustCompile(`[A-Z]`)
    digit_cond := regexp.MustCompile(`[0-9]`)
    whole_cond := regexp.MustCompile(`^[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$`)
    pass_len := utf8.RuneCountInString(s)
    fmt.Println(lower_cond.MatchString(s) && upper_cond.MatchString(s) && digit_cond.MatchString(s) && whole_cond.MatchString(s) && pass_len >= 8)
}
```

See [Go playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/Y6BbdXKF9u)

NOTE: I used `utf8.RuneCountInString` in the demo to make sure even UTF8 string length is parsed correctly. Otherwise, you might use `len(s)` that will count bytes that should suffice for ASCII input.

**Update**

If the performance is not satisfactory, you may consider using a simpler non-regex approach:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    myString := "aSfd46Fgwaq"
    has_digit := false
    has_upper := false
    has_lower := false
    pass_length := len(myString)
    for _, value := range myString {
        switch {
        case value >= '0' && value <= '9':
            has_digit = true
        case value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z':
            has_upper = true
        case value >= 'a' && value <= 'z':
            has_lower = true
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(has_digit && has_upper && has_lower && pass_length >= 8)

}
```

See [another Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/awvIBoLzw7)

Comment: If I use standard lib function to validate string input, will it be faster than using regexp method? regexp method seems need to take time to decode the regex pattern. What would you recommend?